python3 print command does not recognize colored text
Python below opens a yaml file, read some color-formatted text and print it. text1 and text2 somehow remains in text, color is not applied. If I set the text as a variable, it works. So, the way I read the yaml file is not allowing print to recognize the colors. Besides utf-8, I tried with ascii, and others with no luck. any hint?
m.py
import yaml,os,sys

fname_parameter=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/m.yaml"
with open(fname_parameter,encoding='utf-8') as f:
  data=f.read()
  tree=yaml.load(data, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
print("%s"%tree["main"]["text1"])
print("%s"%tree["main"]["text2"])
text="text text \033[31m text3 \033[0m text"
print("%s"%text)

m.yaml
main:
  text1: text text \033[31m text1 \033[0m text
  text2: |
    text text \033[32m text2a \033[0m text                                                     
    text text \033[37m text2b \033[0m text

output:
[rocky@node01 bin]$ python3 m.py
text text \033[31m text1 \033[0m text
text text \033[32m text2a \033[0m text
text text \033[37m text2b \033[0m text
text text  text3  text

# (text3 above was printed in red as expected)

[rocky@node01 bin]$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.18
[rocky@node01 bin]$

